# Difficulty with Caesar Cipher Chi-Squared

Tags: java, encryption, chi-squared, caesar-cipher

In case you are unfamiliar with the cipher. The idea is to be able to encode a message by shifting letters in the alphabet. Ex. d shift 3 -> a. Then be able to decode the message using the crack method. The crack method makes an array full of chi square values (compared to natural alphabetical frequencies in table) for every possible shift (its index) and checks to see which shift has the smallest value. It then takes this value and decodes it using this shift amount.

The problem, is I am getting the smallest chi square value in the wrong address of the array to be able to decode it accurately. I'm not looking for someone to give me the answer, just for where I should look in my code to make the correction.

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Cipher {
//alphabet frequency
static double[] table = {8.2, 1.5, 2.8, 4.3, 12.7, 2.2, 2.0, 6.1, 7.0, 0.2, 0.8, 4.0, 2.4, 6.7,
    7.5, 1.9, 0.1, 6.0, 6.3, 9.1, 2.8, 1.0, 2.4, 0.2, 2.0, 0.1};

//convert letter to number
static int let2nat(char c)
{
    return ((int) c) - 97;
}
//convert number to letter
static char nat2let(int code)
{
    return (char) (code + 97);
}
//shift a letter to another letter shftAmt spaces away
static char shift(int shftAmt, char c)
{
    if (let2nat(c) < 0 || let2nat(c) > 25)
        return c;
    return nat2let((let2nat(c) + shftAmt) % 26);

}
//encodes a string using the given shift amount
static String encode(int shftAmt, String str)
{
    char[] encodedStr = new char[str.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        encodedStr[i] = shift(shftAmt, str.charAt(i));
    return new String(encodedStr);
}
//performs the inverse method to encode
static String decode(int shftAmt, String str)
{
    char[] decodedStr = new char[str.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        decodedStr[i] = shift(0 - shftAmt, str.charAt(i));
    return new String(decodedStr);
}
//determines how many lowercase letters are in the string str
static int lowers(String str)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        if(let2nat(str.charAt(i)) >= 0 && let2nat(str.charAt(i)) <= 25)
            count++;
    return count;
}
//calculates the number of a character in a string
static int count(char c, String str)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        if(c == str.charAt(i))
            counter++;
    return counter;
}
//calculates the percent off num1 to num2
static double percent(int num1, int num2)
{
    return ((double) num1/num2 * 100);
}
//find the ratio frequency of all letters in the string str
static double[] freqs(String str)
{
    double[] count = new double[26];
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        if(let2nat(str.charAt(i)) >= 0 && let2nat(str.charAt(i)) <= 25)
            count[let2nat(str.charAt(i))]++;
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        count[i] = percent((int)count[i], lowers(str));
    return count;
}
//rotates a list n places to the left
static double[] rotate(int n, double[] list)
{
    int j = 0;
    while(j<n){
        double starter = list[0];
        //shift one left
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length-1; i++)
            list[i] = list[i+1];
        list[list.length-1] = starter;
        j++;
    }
    return list;
}
//calculates the chi square value
static double chisqr(double[] os)
{
    double chitotal = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < os.length; i++)
        chitotal += ((Math.pow((os[i] - table[i]), 2)) / table[i]);
    return chitotal;
}
//returns the first position at whcih a value occurs,if returns 999999 then it doesnt exist in the array
static int position(double a, double[] list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        if(list[i] == a)
            return i;
    return 999999;
}
static String crack(String str)
{
    double[] frequencies = freqs(str);
    double[] chisqrValues = new double[26];
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        chisqrValues[i] = chisqr(rotate(i, frequencies));
    int smallestIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 26; i++)
        if(chisqrValues[i] < chisqrValues[smallestIndex])
            smallestIndex = i;
    return decode(smallestIndex, str);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(crack(encode(3, "haskellisfun")));
}

}
```

Comment: Testing has shown that your shift with negative numbers is broken -- please test it yourself and debug it. A simple for loop that runs through the alphabet and shifts in positive and negative direction and prints it out will show you this.

Comment: This is because negative numbers don't mod to positive numbers. You need to mod the int, add the mod value (26, which I change to a const), and mod it again. But this is not the source of your main error.

Comment: [For example](http://pastebin.com/wNheWu6u)

Comment: Well, I don't know what's wrong with your code just yet, but I just got my own `crack(...)` method to work. Cool stuff!

Comment: Java doesn't have a "mod" or "modulo" operator. It's just got a *remainder* operator. It's probably best to keep thinking of it as that so you don't get into trouble when using it.

Comment: sorry man, had a test in this class today. I am going to probably look at it again on Saturday and I am understanding what you mean by the negatives

Comment: okay, i got my decode working by simply changing (0 - shftAmt) to (26-shftAmt) this way the array goes around essentially in a 360... however, as you pointed out, I am still having an issue with it returning the correct value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, your code for shifting is wrong when negative numbers are used as the index parameter, and this is because of how Java handles negative values when the `%` operator is used. To be safe, you should do something like:

```
// shift a letter to another letter shftAmt spaces away
static char shift(int shftAmt, char c) {
  if (let2nat(c) < 0 || let2nat(c) > Z_TO_A - 1) {
     return c;
  } else {
     // do a safe shift
     int result = (let2nat(c) + shftAmt) % Z_TO_A;
     result += Z_TO_A;
     result %= Z_TO_A;
     return nat2let(result);
  }
}
```

But as also mentioned in comments, this isn't the cause of your bug, and to find that bug, you should test each method, best with unit testing, or if not, then your with your own test methods, to be sure that they're all behaving as expected, and if not, at least allowing you to isolate your bug which will put you half way towards solving your problem.

As an aside, my own take on the problem is to not ignore upper case letters as your code does, but since they are part of the text letter frequency, they should be used when calculating our own letter frequency. Something like this could work well:

```
/**
 * 
 * @author hovercraft
 * {@link http://stackoverflow.com/q/31303332/522444}
 */
public class Cipher2 {
   // just ban "magic" numbers
   public static final int A_VALUE = (int) 'a';
   public static final int Z_TO_A = (int) ('z' - 'a') + 1;
   // alphabet frequency
   static double[] table = { 8.2, 1.5, 2.8, 4.3, 12.7, 2.2, 2.0, 6.1, 7.0, 0.2,
         0.8, 4.0, 2.4, 6.7, 7.5, 1.9, 0.1, 6.0, 6.3, 9.1, 2.8, 1.0, 2.4, 0.2,
         2.0, 0.1 };

   // convert letter to number
   static int let2nat(char c) {
      return ((int) c) - A_VALUE;
   }

   // convert number to letter
   static char nat2let(int code) {
      return (char) (code + A_VALUE);
   }

   // shift a letter to another letter shftAmt spaces away
   static char shift(int shftAmt, char c) {
      if (let2nat(c) < 0 || let2nat(c) > Z_TO_A - 1) {
         return c;
      } else {
         // do a safe shift
         int result = (let2nat(c) + shftAmt) % Z_TO_A;
         result += Z_TO_A;
         result %= Z_TO_A;
         return nat2let(result);
      }
   }

   private static String crack(String encrypted) {
      int[] letterCount = new int[Z_TO_A];
      for (char c : encrypted.toCharArray()) {
         letterCount[let2nat(c)]++;
      }
      double[] letterFrequency = new double[Z_TO_A];
      for (int i = 0; i < letterCount.length; i++) {
         letterFrequency[i] = (double) letterCount[i] * 100 / Z_TO_A;
      }

      int index = 0;
      double minChiSqrSum = calcChiSqrSum(index, letterFrequency);
      for (int i = 0; i < Z_TO_A; i++) {
         double chiSqrSum = calcChiSqrSum(i, letterFrequency);
         if (chiSqrSum < minChiSqrSum) {
            minChiSqrSum = chiSqrSum;
            index = i;
         }
      }
      return encode(index, encrypted);
   }

   private static double calcChiSqrSum(int i, double[] letterFrequency) {
      double sum = 0.0;
      for (int j = 0; j < letterFrequency.length; j++) {
         double observed = letterFrequency[j];
         int tableIndex = (i + j + Z_TO_A) % Z_TO_A;
         double expected = table[tableIndex];
         double delta = observed - expected;
         double chiSqr = delta * delta / expected;
         sum += chiSqr;
      }
      return sum;
   }

   private static String encode(int shift, String text) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
         // convert all upper case to lower case
         // this is a judgment call on my part
         c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
         if (let2nat(c) >= 0 && let2nat(c) < Z_TO_A) {
            sb.append(shift(shift, c));
         }
      }
      return sb.toString();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String test1 = "Hello world. How is it going? It's going fine with me";
      String test2 = "When, in the course of human events, it becomes "
            + "necessary for one portion of the family of man to assume "
            + "among the people of the earth a position different from "
            + "that which they have hitherto occupied, but one to which "
            + "the laws of nature and of nature's God entitle them, "
            + "a decent respect to the opinions of mankind";

      // let's throw it for a complete loop: ... but it works!
      String test3 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing "
            + "elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore "
            + "magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud "
            + "exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo "
            + "consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in "
            + "voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. "
            + "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in "
            + "culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

      // an unfair test:
      String test4 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

      String test5 = "haskellisfun";
      String[] tests = { test1, test2, test3, test4, test5 };

      for (String test : tests) {
         System.out.println(crack(encode(6, test)));
      }
   }
}
```